# Opposite of emoji savvy

Tags: american-english, british-english, neologisms

Is there any word which describes the man who doesn't know how to use emojis

Comment: 'Emoji ignorant'? I don't think this deserves the 'urban-legend' tag.

Comment: Emoji illiterate

Comment: Are you _sure_ he doesn’t know how to use them? Maybe we should do a semi-colonoscopy to find out ;-)

Comment: "emoji challenged" is another way to coin it

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could make your own?

How about: **emojionally confused**

e.g.
A: I can't believe Fred used the "xD" emoji to reply to a serious message!
B: Wow, he must be **emojionally confused**.

Comment: Or _emojionally challenged_ would also work. (The word _challenged_ in particular is often used in tongue-in-cheek quips nowadays: _He’s not short, he’s vertically challenged._)

Comment: @J.R. ooh, I like that one! (My friends sometimes say that I am *vertically challenged*, but I prefer *lacking on the y-axis*)

Comment: @as4s4hetic Nice answer with a touch of humour!

Comment: @as4s4hetic if we are going that way, then i guess emojionally naive would be better i guess